# Saving Filenames with Condition

Tags: python, file, input

I'm trying to save the names of files that fulfill a certain condition.
I think the easiest way to do this would make a short Python program that imports and reads the files, checks if the condition is met, and (assuming it is met) then saves the names of the files.

I have data files with just two columns and four rows, something like this:

```
 a:    5
 b:    5
 c:    6
 de:    7
```

I want to save the names of the files (or part of the name of the files, if that's a simple fix, otherwise I can just `sed` the file afterwards) of the data files that have the 4th number ([3:1]) greater than 8. I tried importing the files with `numpy`, but it said it couldn't import the letters in the first column.

Another way I was considering trying to do it was from the command line something along the lines of `cat *.dat >> something.txt`but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

The code I've tried to write up to get this to work is:

```
import fileinput
import glob
import numpy as np

#Filter to find value > 8

#Globbing value datafiles
file_list = glob.glob("/path/to/*.dat")

#Creating output file containing
f = open('list.txt', 'w')

#Looping over files
for file in file_list:
        #For each file in the directory, isolating the filename
        filename = file.split('/')[-1]
        #Opening the files, checking if value is greater than 8
        a = np.loadtxt("file", delimiter=' ', usecols=1)
        if a[3:0] > 8:
                print >> f,  filename
f.close()
```

When I do this, I get an error that says `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`, but I don't know what that's referring to.

Comment: Please show the code you are asking about.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: in this case are you wanting 7 in this example data?

Comment: I put up the code that wasn't working, @ScottHunter. 
In this case, I want the name of the file, if 7 (well, the number that's in that spot) is greater than or equal to 8.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using

```
import fileinput
import glob
import numpy as np

#Filter to find value > 8

#Globbing datafiles
file_list =  glob.glob("/path/to/*.dat")

 #Creating output file containing
 f = open('list.txt', 'w')

 #Looping over files
 for file in file_list:
        #For each file in the directory, isolating the filename
        filename = file.split('/')[-1]
        #Opening the files, checking if value is greater than 8
        a = np.genfromtxt(file)
        if a[3,1] > 8:
                f.write(filename + "\n")
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to tell exactly what you want but maybe something like this

```
from glob import glob
from re import findall
fpattern = "/path/to/*.dat"

def test(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
        try:
           return int(findall("\d+",f.read())[3])>8
        except IndexError:
           pass

matches = [fname for fname in glob(fpattern) if test(fname)]
print matches
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got an error saying:
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: did you do `from glob import glob` ? (also I had a small typo... that is now fixed) ... what line is that error on?